# Shell print numbers that are smaller than first number

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to print the numbers that are smaller than first number

```
./8d 100 5 8 6
```

so my result should be 5 8 6

```
 #!/bin/bash
    for i in $*
    do
    if [[ $1 > $i ]]; then
        echo "Num " $i
    fi
    done
```

But I dont get any result. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `-lt`/`-eq`/`-gt` to compare integers.

```
if [[ $1 -gt $i ]]; then
    echo "Num " $i
fi
```

Here's [some details](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) on comparison operators.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it's doing *lexical* comparisons, not numerical. `10` and `1` are both smaller than `100` lexically, but the numbers you supplied are larger.

I'd code that like this, I think it's clearer

```
#!/bin/bash
base=$1
shift
for n do 
    (( base > n )) && echo $n 
done
```

and

```
$ smaller 100 5 8 1234 6 100
5
8
6
```